# How to exclude element through its id using queryselector

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using the w3school's Tryit Editor to select a `<p>` element inside a `<div>`. Trying to blur contents of the `<div>` excluding the `<p>` does not work. This is what I mean:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("#blurred:not(#text)").style.webkitFilter = "blur(10px)";
}
```

```html
<br>

<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<div id="blurred">
  <p id="text">A paragraph with class="example".</p>

  <p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in the document with class="example".</p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

How can I exclude the `<p>` with id `#text` from the blur?

Comment: `"#blurred *:not(#text)"`

Comment: Just add space `#blurred :not(#text)` between not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select all the child elements using `*`. and then use the `:not` selector to exclude `#text`

```
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("#blurred *:not(#text)").style.webkitFilter =
    "blur(10px)";
}
```

OR you can directly target all the `p` elements within `#blurred` like

`#blurred p:not(#text)`

Comment: This considers all elements not just the `<p>` element

Answer (score 0):

Target the `p` with that id you want to exclude:

```
#blurred p:not(#text)
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  const div = document.querySelector("#blurred p:not(#text)")
  div.style.webkitFilter = "blur(10px)";
}
```

```html
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<div id="blurred">
  <p id="text">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
  <p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in the document with class="example".</p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the backdrop-filter property to blur only the area behind the contents of your div only. I did it using jQuery.

```
function myFunction() {
  const div = document.querySelector("#blurred p:not(#text)")
  $(div).css("backdrop-filter", "blur(10px)");
}
```

or a cleaner version:

```
function myFunction() {
  $("#blurred p:not(#text)").css("backdrop-filter", "blur(10px)");
}
```